# Rails 4.0.3 - has_many through undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass - only on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have a branch model

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true

    has_many :company_branches
    has_many :companies, -> { uniq }, :through => :company_branches
end
```

and a company model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :company_branches
    has_many :branches, -> { uniq }, :through => :company_branches
end
```

The company can have many branches through company_branches

```
class CompanyBranch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :branch, touch: true
    belongs_to :company, touch: true
end
```

On my local machine everything works fine but when I try to save the form on my production Server I get: `NoMethodError (undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass)`

The call in my controller is @company.update_attributes(company_params) - The controller receives the branch_ids as array, like `branch_ids => [1, 2, 3]`

Interesting part of the controller(It fails at @company.update_attributes(company_params)):

```
class Admin::CompaniesController < Admin::AdminController
    respond_to :html, :json
    load_and_authorize_resource


    def update
        @company = Company.find(params[:id])
        @company.update_attributes(company_params)
        ....
    end


    private
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:id, branch_ids: [])
    end
end
```

To clarify: I tried many things and currently only have one branch on my production server. Even with that one single branch I get the error when I try to save it.

**Edit**: I posted the full stacktrace here: http://pastebin.com/tw6hjkyF

Comment: Where is your app hosted? Have you run rake db:migrate?

Comment: The app is hosted on an own server. We deploy with capistrano so we have no migration problem. The app is running for serveral years now.

Comment: If it's failing at @company.update_attributes() etc with a nil class, won't that mean that your @company instance is nil?

Comment: I already checked that. The problem are the branches, not the company. As I wrote, everything works fine locally.

Comment: Stack trace might help

Comment: would you mind post a answer, I'm very interested to known the reason.

Comment: I will post the answer when I find out what happens. I will edit my post and add the stacktrace.

Comment: @OliverM I added the stacktrace. I hope that helps.

Comment: Have you just upgraded to ruby 2.2 from ruby < 2.2? There was an Active Record bug which was fixed for Rails 4.1/2. See the very top of your stack trace, has_cached_counter.

Comment: I think that's the right hint. I just noticed I'm running 2.0.0 on my local machine and 2.2.0 on my production server and wanted to have a look if it has something to do with that.

Comment: Ok I think that's probably it! Glad we could get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug with Active Record, you'll need to Upgrade Rails, or downgrade ruby from 2.2 to 2.1.8 or lower.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the reason.